# How do I find where a network drive is mapped to in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, network-drive

How do I find out where a network drive on my work machine is mapped to?

One of the four has the location in brackets next to it but the other three don't.

Comment: "One of the four has the location in brackets next to it but the other 3 don't." -- It looks weird. Can you upload an image illustrating this situation?

Comment: Better answer at https://superuser.com/q/465038/2366.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Go to *Start » Run*, type in `cmd` and press OK.

In the `cmd` box, paste the following, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run it.

```
wmic path Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType="4" get DeviceID, ProviderName
```

Doing the above but typing in  `NET USE` instead of copying the above also yields the same result.

Answer (score 64):

In Windows Explorer, you can also switch the view to "Details" and right-click the header to add a column named "Network location":

[image: Windows Explorer Network Location]

Helps if the admin has disabled CMD for you (!)

Comment: I couldn't find "Network Location" on the list on Win 7 Pro.

Comment: @pghcpa I see the option only in the root of "My Computer", not inside any of the network drives. Are you looking there?

Comment: note* This gives the share path, but not the disk path.

Comment: if your drive is at location '\\name\Data1' you can retrieve the IP by:     'ping name'

Comment: Also works on Win8.1 Enterprise.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the net use or the Win32_LogicalDisk will not show some of the mapped drives, powershell cmd:

```
gwmi win32_mappedlogicaldisk | select name, providername
```

will work then. The corresponding windows cmd is the following:

```
wmic path win32_mappedlogicaldisk get DeviceID, ProviderName
```